# Haskell cassava (Data.Csv): Carry along additional columns

Tags: csv, parsing, haskell

I have two .csv files

**A.csv:**

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
5,4,3,2,1
```

**B.csv**

```
A,E,B,C,F
6,7,8,9,1
4,3,4,5,6
```

I would like to read them in Haskell with strict parsing rules for the variables `A`, `B` and `C`. I would then like to apply complex merge and filter operations to the rows of **A.csv** and **B.csv** and create a file **C.csv** from the result. The code block at the end of this post essentially covers this functionality.

*Question:*

I would now like to do all of this while keeping the variables `D`, `E` and `F` around. In my real dataset I have an *unknown and arbitrary number of such additional columns*. I can not easily represent them in the respective data type (`ABC` below). All of them should stay and be properly represented in the output dataset.

With the code below, **C.csv** looks like this:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
5,4,3
6,8,9
4,4,5
```

I would instead like to have a result like this:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
1,2,3,4,5,_
5,4,3,2,1,_
6,8,9,_,7,1
4,4,5,_,3,6
```

Is there a way to do this with cassava? Do I have to write a custom parser from scratch to get this functionality? How would I go about this?

---

This example code lacks the desired feature. It is a self-contained [stack script](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#stacks-script-interpreter).

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-18.7 script --package cassava,bytestring,vector

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.Csv as C
import qualified Data.Vector as V

data ABC = ABC {a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: Int} deriving Show

instance C.FromNamedRecord ABC where
    parseNamedRecord m =
        ABC <$> m C..: "A" <*> m C..: "B" <*> m C..: "C"

instance C.ToNamedRecord ABC where
    toNamedRecord ABC {..} =
        C.namedRecord ["A" C..= a, "B" C..= b, "C" C..= c]

decodeABC :: B.ByteString -> [ABC]
decodeABC x =
    case C.decodeByName x of
        Left err -> error err
        Right (_,xs) -> V.toList xs

header :: C.Header
header = V.fromList ["A", "B", "C"]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    fileA <- B.readFile "A.csv"
    fileB <- B.readFile "B.csv"
    let decodedA = decodeABC fileA
    let decodedB = decodeABC fileB
    putStrLn $ show decodedA
    putStrLn $ show decodedB
    B.writeFile "C.csv" $ C.encodeByName header (decodedA ++ decodedB)
```

---

This code includes the desired feature (thanks to the input of @Daniel Wagner):

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-18.7 script --package cassava,bytestring,vector,unordered-containers

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.Csv as C
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM
import qualified Data.Vector as V

data ABC = ABC {a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: Int, addCols :: C.NamedRecord} deriving Show

abcDefinedCols = ["A", "B", "C"]
abcRefHashMap = HM.fromList $ map (\x -> (x, ())) abcDefinedCols

instance C.FromNamedRecord ABC where
    parseNamedRecord m =
        pure ABC
        <*> m C..: "A"
        <*> m C..: "B"
        <*> m C..: "C"
        <*> pure (m `HM.difference` abcRefHashMap)

instance C.ToNamedRecord ABC where
    toNamedRecord m =
        (addCols m) `HM.union` C.namedRecord ["A" C..= a m, "B" C..= b m, "C" C..= c m]

decodeABC :: B.ByteString -> [ABC]
decodeABC x =
    case C.decodeByName x of
        Left err -> error err
        Right (_,xs) -> V.toList xs

makeCompleteHeader :: [ABC] -> C.Header
makeCompleteHeader ms = V.fromList $ abcDefinedCols ++ HM.keys (HM.unions (map addCols ms))

combineABCs :: [ABC] -> [ABC] -> [ABC]
combineABCs xs1 xs2 =
    let simpleSum = xs1 ++ xs2
        addColKeys = HM.keys (HM.unions (map addCols simpleSum))
        toAddHashMap = HM.fromList (map (\k -> (k, "n/a")) addColKeys)
    in map (\x -> x { addCols = fillAddCols (addCols x) toAddHashMap }) simpleSum
    where
        fillAddCols :: C.NamedRecord -> C.NamedRecord -> C.NamedRecord
        fillAddCols cur toAdd = HM.union cur (toAdd `HM.difference` cur)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    fileA <- B.readFile "A.csv"
    fileB <- B.readFile "B.csv"
    let decodedA = decodeABC fileA
    let decodedB = decodeABC fileB
    putStrLn $ show decodedA
    putStrLn $ show decodedB
    let ab = combineABCs decodedA decodedB
    B.writeFile "C.csv" $ C.encodeByName (makeCompleteHeader ab) ab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data ABCPlus = ABCPlus { a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: Int, d :: NamedRecord } deriving Show

instance FromNamedRecord ABCPlus where
    parseNamedRecord m = pure ABC
        <*> m .: "A"
        <*> m .: "B"
        <*> m .: "C"
        <*> pure m -- or perhaps: pure (m `HM.difference` HM.fromList [("A", ()), ("B", ()), ("C", ())])

instance ToNamedRecord ABCPlus where
     toNamedRecord m = d m -- or perhaps: d m `HM.union` namedRecord ["A" .= a m, "B" .= b m, "C" .= c m]

headers :: [ABCPlus] -> Header
headers ms = header $ ["A", "B", "C"] ++ HM.keys (relevant combined) where
    relevant m = m `HM.difference` HM.fromList [("A", ()), ("B", ()), ("C", ())] -- or perhaps: m
    combined = HM.unions [relevantKeys (d m) | m <- ms]
```

Comment: Thank you! Took me a while to understand, but it works perfectly fine! I added a second section of example code with the desired feature based on your input.